# using Resource Dictionary in wpf

Tags: wpf, resources, dictionary

hello i am trying to use the wpf dictionay and i am having the follwing exception:

```
exception Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.'
Line number '6' and line position '80'."}   
System.Exception {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseExceptionty}
```

i think that i acted by the book i created a folder and named it Resources,inside it i put two 
Resource dictionaries ,ColorsAndBrushes.xaml and DefaultStyles.xaml,
i typed :

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ColorsAndBrushes.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/DefaultStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

inside the app.xaml file but still i am getting this exception, i would like to know what i am doing wrong , thanks in advance for your help.

```
EDIT:
```

i just did i found out what was my problem ther was a staticResource call on the Xaml file which wasnt defined sorry for the waste of your time

Comment: Can you post your entire App.xaml

Comment: i just did i found out what was my problem ther was a staticResource call on the Xaml file which wasnt defined sorry for the waste of your time

Comment: If you want to keep the question here, post the solution as an answer and accept it in a couple of days. That way anyone else with the same problem in the future will be helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay so i made a mistake and left Color = "{StaticResource violetColor}" attribute
which did not exist